# Hadoop CDH4 and Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop

Has anyone been successful in building an eclipse plugin for Juno against the CDH4 installation?

I've seen CDH3 all over the net.  Looking for CDH4.
Thanks much.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you're referring to the Hadoop Eclipse plugin or a plugin to develop code against CDH4. I'll answer both questions.

Developing against CDH4 in Juno:
By far, the easiest way to write applications against CDH4 components in Eclipse (any version), is by using [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse) and adding the Cloudera Maven repository to your pom.xml. In fact, a significant portion of folks at Cloudera (including myself), do this regularly. Recently, one of our engineers (Natty) wrote a nice blog post about getting started with CDH4, Maven, and [Eclipse](https://blog.cloudera.com/) (and other IDEs). Otherwise, nothing special is required to write apps against CDH4 other than having the JARs around. You can also browse through the Cloudera Maven repository [here](https://repository.cloudera.com/ui/).

The Hadoop Plugin:
Long ago, a plugin for Eclipse existed that allowed for MR job execution and some other bits. It has, however, been unmaintained for a very long time (at least two to three years now). I don't think anyone ever updated it to work with Juno--, let alone Juno, itself.

Comment: Hi.  I'm referring to the Hadoop Eclipse Plugin.  I'm trying to build it, and I followed the guidance where I perform an ant call on the folder Hadoop-mapreduce-project, after updating build.properties in the eclipse-plugin folder.  Unfortunatly it does not build the correct jar.  I'm missing something, and I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions found at: http://iredlof.com/part-4-compile-hadoop-v1-0-4-eclipse-plugin-on-ubuntu-12-10/

System: Local: Windows 7, Eclipse Juno (4.2.2), hadoop-1.2.1. Remote: Debian 7.1 with the same hadoop version.

I should mention that I built the plugin against vanilla hadoop-1.2.1 freshly downloaded from apache.

Not everything works with the plugin: I can add new MR location (remote in my case), I can browse/upload/download/delete files from DFS,  but BUT I cannot run my code (using Run as ... Run to Hadoop). The console writes "ClassNotFoundException: WordCountReducer"

A good thing is that the jar generated by eclipse can be manually uploaded to MR master and started from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Hadoop Eclipse plugin at this GitHub Repository. https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin.

A post here introduces how to integrate CDH5 and Eclipse Luna. http://speedy-elephant.blogspot.com/2015/08/the-real-getting-started-guide-cloudera.html